# Unable to install 'fancyimpute' in Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to install `fancyimpute` in Anaconda through Anaconda Powershell Prompt but it is resulting in an error. I tried many solutions but none worked for me.

I used the following commands to install `fancyimpute`:

`conda install ecos`
`conda install CVXcanon`
`pip install fancyimpute`

The error which I'm getting during pip install fancyimpute is as follows:

````
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tensorflow->fancyimpute) (41.0.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: fancyimpute, knnimpute, np-utils, scs, gast, termcolor, absl-py, dill
  Building wheel for fancyimpute (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\32\c9\50\1332a2e8fc9dfa2cbc109f5232c5114155184ab676fdad75a0
  Building wheel for knnimpute (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\a3\92\31\c3f8864714e9938396c3a68d8c542531f7e2d7862bb750b2e3
  Building wheel for np-utils (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\e7\66\d8\fda30ac7283132e9924da37745e2864723f87926efff1027ee
  Building wheel for scs (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Mandeep\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-assnbjrs\\scs\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-edkex6p8' --python-tag cp36:
  ERROR: Namespace(blas64=False, extraverbose=False, float32=False, gpu=False, int32=False, scs=False)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\scs
  copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\scs
  running build_ext
  mkl_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  blas_mkl_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  blas_opt_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  lapack_opt_info:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt']
      library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
  Could not locate executable g77
  Could not locate executable f77
  Could not locate executable ifort
  Could not locate executable ifl
  Could not locate executable f90
  Could not locate executable DF
  Could not locate executable efl
  Could not locate executable gfortran
  Could not locate executable f95
  Could not locate executable g95
  Could not locate executable efort
  Could not locate executable efc
  Could not locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
      the BLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
      the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  {}
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  {}
  Exception in thread Thread-1:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
      self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 69, in _getall
      all_packages.extend(_distutils_findvs.findall())
  OSError: Error 80070002

  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scs
  Running setup.py clean for scs
  Building wheel for gast (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\5c\2e\7e\a1d4d4fcebe6c381f378ce7743a3ced3699feb89bcfbdadadd
  Building wheel for termcolor (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\7c\06\54\bc84598ba1daf8f970247f550b175aaaee85f68b4b0c5ab2c6
  Building wheel for absl-py (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\ee\98\38\46cbcc5a93cfea5492d19c38562691ddb23b940176c14f7b48
  Building wheel for dill (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\5b\d7\0f\e58eae695403de585269f4e4a94e0cd6ca60ec0c202936fa4a
Successfully built fancyimpute knnimpute np-utils gast termcolor absl-py dill
Failed to build scs
Installing collected packages: knnimpute, osqp, scs, dill, multiprocess, cvxpy, keras-applications, keras-preprocessing, keras, np-utils, astor, markdown, absl-py, grpcio, protobuf, tensorboard, mock, tensorflow-estimator, gast, termcolor, tensorflow, fancyimpute
  Running setup.py install for scs ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Mandeep\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-assnbjrs\\scs\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qtt9_e2k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: Namespace(blas64=False, extraverbose=False, float32=False, gpu=False, int32=False, scs=False)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\scs
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\scs
    running build_ext
    mkl_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    blas_mkl_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    blas_opt_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    lapack_opt_info:
        libraries = ['mkl_rt']
        library_dirs = ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
        include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable DF
    Could not locate executable efl
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    {}
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    {}
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 69, in _getall
        all_packages.extend(_distutils_findvs.findall())
    OSError: Error 80070002

    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Mandeep\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-assnbjrs\\scs\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qtt9_e2k\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Mandeep\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-assnbjrs\scs\
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>```
````

Comment: try upgrading pip using `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and Install Microsoft Build Tools 2015 (If don't have it already)
2. Download [scs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scs) and [cvxpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxpy) wheels for your version of Python. (For me cp36 with amd64 worked, don't know why cp37 didn't work even though my Python version is 3.7.3)
3. Move .whl files to the subdir for Anaconda Prompt
4. Run following commands

   conda install ecos

   conda install (scs filename).whl

   conda install (cvxpy filename).whl

   pip install fancyimpute

Note: If .whl runs with an error, download and try other version.