# how to pip install fancyimpute?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, fancyimpute

in my case, I also have python 3.7.7 but couldn't install fancyimpute as well
I tried cp36 , and cp37 version. and I already installed visual studio C++ 2015

here's my error log.

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for scs
Running setup.py clean for scs
Failed to build cvxpy scs
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cvxpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your problem still persists. I installed the vs and reinstalled cvxpy, then got the error resolved.
[Unable to install 'fancyimpute' in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414925/unable-to-install-fancyimpute-in-anaconda)
and
https://www.cvxpy.org/install/index.html#conda
may give you more info on this problem.